# Error in `geom_polypath()` Problem while converting geom to grob, Caused by error in `as.vector()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, spatial, geom

I am trying to use `geom_spatial_polygon` but regardless of the dataset I use, if my data is numeric, integer, factor or character, or if I start the plot with `basemap()` or `ggplot()` I receive the following error: Problem while converting geom to
grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `as.vector()`:
! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

I would really appreciate any advice on how to fix this as I have been stuck here for over a week!

````
# creating data
lat<-c(80.30707, 80.29094, 80.29137, 80.29221,80.29109, 80.28888, 80.27666, 80.27193,80.23415, 80.22916, 80.21851, 80.20874)
long<-c(52.53969,  52.43050,  52.41305,  52.37471, 52.34166,  52.31138,  52.19777,  52.18138,52.33222,  52.47833,  52.49959,  52.61820)
group<-(rep(0.1,12))
df<-data.frame(lat, long, group)
df$group<-as.factor(df$group)

# loading packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggOceanMaps)

# plot
basemap(limits=c(5,50,70,82))+
    geom_spatial_polygon(data=df,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color=NA,fill="lightblue") ```

#error message
Error in `geom_polypath()`:
    ! Problem while converting geom to
grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `as.vector()`:
    ! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Backtrace:
    1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
4. ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built(data)
5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
...
23. base::with.default(...)
24. base::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
25. base::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
26. base::paste(fill, colour, alpha, size, linetype)
28. base::as.character.default(`<stndrdGn>`)
````

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly for me (R 4.2.1/ggOceanMaps_1.3.4)

Comment: Thanks for checking this - I have the same versions as you for both... It must be something to do with my own R environment then :/